# Variable is not defined error in my Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I'm developing a Firefox add-on. When I run it, I open up the browser console and it says, `AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox is not defined :browser.xul`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://Uedit/skin/skin.css" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE Uedit SYSTEM "chrome://Uedit/locale/translations.dtd">
<overlay id="Uedit-overlay" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">
    <script src="Uedit.js" />
    <toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
        <toolbarbutton id="Uedit" class="toolbarbutton-1" label="Edit HTML" tooltiptext="Edit HTML" oncommand="AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox.Uedit()" />
    </toolbarpalette>
</overlay>
```

The toolbar button that calls a function which is part of an object (`AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox`).

I double-checked the names and they both match. Is it because the script doesn't load properly? I'm sure it's not that variable names can't start with capital letters.

```
var AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox={ // This is for "wrapping the loose variables."
```

Both the file's references are the exact same. Could it be because the script didn't load at all?

```
<toolbarbutton id="Uedit" class="toolbarbutton-1" label="Edit HTML" tooltiptext="Edit HTML" oncommand="AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox.Uedit()" />
```

I tried changing the relative URL (`<script src="Uedit.js" />`) to an absolute URL (`<script src="chrome://Uedit/Uedit.js" />`) in the browser.xul, but now it just returns a blank error message.

> [image]
>   Weird blank error message.

These errors cause the rest of the add-on to not work at all, so I can't continue developing it until this is fixed. What're some possible solutions?

### EDIT:

I figured out a solution. I have to put a line of JavaScript before the first statement.

```
var AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox = { // Will not work!
    ...
```

If I put a `console.log` in the front, for example.

```
console.log("");
var AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox = { // This will work!
    ...
```

The only question is, why does this work?

Comment: Please do not use screen captures to include source code and error messages. Such things should be included in the question as text with the appropriate formatting.  Doing so permits people to search on such contents and to cut & paste the information for testing and creating answers.

Comment: Without code, this question may be off-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working the way I want?**") must include: A) the desired behavior; B) a specific problem or error *and* C) **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** all ***in the question itself***. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Your question has not received many responses, not because we are uninterested in helping you, but because you have made it hard for us to do so. You have not provided enough information. We need to know what type of add-on (i.e. overlay, restartless, add-on SDK). At a minimum, we need source code to be able to debug. With the very minimal (incomplete!) information you have provided (in a very inconvenient format, screen captures), we would have to be psychic to be able to give you decent answers.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured out a solution. I have to put a line of JavaScript before the first statement.

```
var AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox = { // Will not work!
    ...
```

If I put a `console.log` in the front, for example.

```
console.log("foo bar");
var AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox = { // This will work!
    ...
```

I solved the problem myself, although the solution is strange.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to the `Uedit.js` file is wrong.  You should use an absolute path in your xul overlay.

Comment: I did that, but now the whole entire thing doesn't work at all anymore. There is a console error message, but it's blank and all it says is "browser.xul: line #5." (where I put the absolute url)

Answer (score -1):

As [erikvold has said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30746870/3773011), the link to your `Uedit.js` script is wrong. This is the minimum that is wrong and is the thing that is complained about in the console: `browser.xul:5` is line 5 in `browser.xul`, which is:

```
<script src="Uedit.js" />
```

You state that you have tried:

```
<script src="chrome://Uedit/Uedit.js" />
```

That will not work. At a minimum, it should be something like:

```
<script src="chrome://Uedit/content/Uedit.js" type="application/x-javascript" />
```

Note the `content/` after `//Uedit/`. However, that being correct assumes you have set up your [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) with an appropriate `content` line in addition to the other ones implied by your code (`skin` and `locale`). It also assumes that `Uedit.js` is in that directory. Assuming that the directory structure of your add-on is normal, the content line in your *chrome.manifest* file would look something like:

```
content        Uedit        chrome/content/
```

As to it actually working, there is no way for us to know if it will work as you have not included the source code that defines all of `AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox` and specifically not `AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox.Uedit()`. For instance, in addition to the above problem, there could easily be a syntax error that prevents the script from loading. Such a syntax error would cause the console to report that `AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox` was undefined when you attempt to execute `AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox.Uedit()` as the code for the `toolbarbutton`'s `oncommand`.

You can easily test to see if your `Uedit.js` script is loading by having something print in the console when the script loads (i.e. outside the definition of `AMO_Uedit_Beta_Firefox`).

Comment: As I commented on Erikvold's post, the absolute URL doesn't work!

Comment: @NarawaGames The absolute URL which you have in your question `chrome://Uedit/Uedit.js` would, of course, not work. It would need to be something like **`chrome://Uedit/content/Uedit.js`** (as I stated above). You would also need the `content` line in `chrome.manifest` I am glad you have found a solution. Next time, please provide us with enough information to be able to help you.

Comment: @NarawaGames, Interesting. I would be interested in knowing the directory structure you are using, where the *Uedit.js* located within those directories, and the contents of your chrome.manifest.

Comment: The directory structure is exactly like what it says in the tutorial, except the JS file is called Uedit instead of linkTargetFinder. (https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)